# Find frame on the top of the application

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to move my application 20.0f down and put a label above it. My application supports both horizontal and vertical orientation. I can't figure out how to set the frame for my label. I know there is a dynamic way to do it but I can't figure it out. I appreciate a little help here. As you see in the picture, I want to put the label in the pink area.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are constructing your app window's `rootViewController` correctly, that view controller has a UIView, its `view`, that occupies the entire screen (except for the status bar). Its origin is at the top left, just under status bar. So you want your label to be at `{0,0}` as a subview of your root view controller's view. Do not try to put it outside the root view controller, e.g. directly in the UIWindow; that's wrong and you'll just confuse yourself.

Comment: Thanx, my problem was exactly what you said, i was adding it to the UIWindow. Now {0,0} works generally.

Answer (score 0):

When adding the label you want its width to be the same as the width of the bounds of the view you are about to add it to.

Then, if you are not using autoLayout, to handle rotation you will want to set its autoresizing mask to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyAppDelegate *delegate=(MyAppDelegat*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
CGRect frame=delegate.window.rootviewController.view.frame;
frame.origin.y+=20.0f;
delegate.window.rootviewController.view.frame=frame;

UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithRect:CGRectMake(0,0,width,height)];
[delegate.window addSubView:label];
```

Add the autoresizing mask to the label with flexible width flag.So that it resizes when you rotate